# grunt-mocha - assertion inside $.get fails

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gruntjs, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to hook up grunt-mocha with requireJS to do some unit testing, it works great, except I can't seem to test ajax calls.

I've got a repo up with the code :  https://bitbucket.org/IamHttP/grunt-mocha-tests/overview

the specific file can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/IamHttP/grunt-mocha-tests/src/e7f1b67ac61489fc516a532e072aed4f068edcca/tests/testJqueryAjax.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

The code itself is pasted here :

```
describe('testJqueryAjax', function(){

    it('fetch data from an xhr', function(done){
        this.timeout(3000);

        require(['jquery'],function($){

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.github.com',
                success: function(str){
                    try{
                        chai.assert.equal( 1 , 1 );
                        done();
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        done(e);
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function(){
                try{
                    chai.assert.ok( false );
                    done();
                }
                catch(e){
                    done(e);
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

The problem :

The ajax request always fails, no matter where I'm pointing it to. The `.fail` function is always called.

I'm guessing it's a problem with phantomJS not working well with jQuery's $.ajax call, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you suspect PhantomJS being the problem, did you try loading the test in a real browser? That's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Thanks, as suspected, it works fine from the browser, I guess it's a phantomJS issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding a configuration option to phantomJS.

this was done using the grunt task for mocha :

```
    mocha : {
        all : {
            src : ['tests/testrunner.html']
        },
        options : {
            run: true,
            page: {
                settings: {
                    webSecurityEnabled: false,  // disable cors checks in phantomjs
                },
            },
        },
```

note the webSecurityEnabled option.